# How to play video in videoview

Tags: java, android, video, android-videoview

I have tried to play video but it is not showing anything in `VideoView`
Here is my code:

```
 tvvid.setMediaController(new MediaController(AllPostActivity.this));
 tvvid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("content://media/external/video/media/89962"));
 tvvid.requestFocus();
 tvvid.start();
```

I have generate **output** as video `file "content://media/external/video/media/89962"`
how to play video in `videoView` by using above video path.

i have tried by this path also `/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20171208-WA0004.mp4` still not showing anything

> Error opening /sys/class/power_supply/bms/resistance
>                                                           java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/power_supply/bms/resistance:
>   open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>                                                               at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
>                                                               at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:76)
>                                                               at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:103)
>                                                               at java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:66)
>                                                               at com.motorola.motocare.util.LineReader.(LineReader.java:20)
>                                                               at com.motorola.motocare.util.LineReader$1.(LineReader.java:53)
>                                                               at com.motorola.motocare.util.LineReader.firstLineReader(LineReader.java:53)
>                                                               at com.motorola.motocare.util.BatteryUtils.getBatteryResistance(BatteryUtils.java:130)
>                                                               at com.motorola.motocare.action.BatteryLevelAction.onReceiveImpl(BatteryLevelAction.java:42)
>                                                               at com.motorola.motocare.util.BackgroundReceiver$1.run(BackgroundReceiver.java:14)
>                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                               at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
>                                                            Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or
>   directory)
>                                                               at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
>                                                               at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)

Comment: want to play Internal videos or from Server URl' video ?

Comment: have you added permission?

Comment: internal video for now..

Comment: yes permissions have already added and it is working for image

Comment: Is there any warning/error in Logcat?

Comment: I have doubt on url path. Please check if file available on that path.

Comment: i have tried by this path also "/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20171208-WA0004.mp4" still not showing anything

Comment: there is no warning and error...@samir Bhatt

Answer (score 0):

Below is a complete working code for you:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import java.io.File;
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private File mainMashupVideoFileName = "your_file_path/file_name.mp4";

    private void playMyVideoView(File fileName, boolean isMainMashup) {
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        vv_main_video.setMediaController(mediaController);
        vv_main_video.setVideoURI(Uri.fromFile(fileName));

        vv_main_video.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //Resource has been loaded to the video view player and ready to play.
            }
        });

        vv_main_video.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //Can change play pause icon
            }
        });

        vv_main_video.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //playPauseVideos();
                return false;
            }
        });

        vv_main_video.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                //Do nothing
                return true;
            }
        });

        vv_main_video.requestFocus();
        vv_main_video.start();
    } //End of  run VideoView

    private void playPauseVideos() {
        if (vv_main_video.isPlaying()) {
            vv_main_video.pause();
        } else {
            vv_main_video.requestFocus();
            vv_main_video.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Add following permissions in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Must check that the permissions are enabled for your app.

Try and let me know your feedback.